# jQuery Validate plugin does not set valid class on input element on successful remote validation

Tags: jquery-validate

So here's the problem. I have a form that's being validated using the jQuery Validation plugin by Jörn Zaefferer. I have validation working fine except for one component i.e. remote validation. Actually, remote validation does work but not as intended. When I enter some data in the username input and "focus out", the data is validated on the server and depending on the username availability the server responds with the string true or false. Now, on the client side, I expect the validation plugin to add the "error" or "valid" class to the input element based on the response from the server. The plugin does add the "error" class when it receives a false response string from the server, but fails to add the "valid" class upon receiving true response string.

To add to the mystery if click inside the username input and focus out the second time, voila! the valid class gets added. A point to be noted: The remote Ajax validation does not run on the second focus out since the input field data has not changed. The plugin is merely adding the class based on the last response (that's what I think) it received from the server. Weird.

Initially, I thought the problem could be due to asynchronous Ajax. But I changed it to synchronous. Problem persisted. I have throughly checked the response from the server in Firebug console. And I can see "true" or "false" strings (without quotes) as response.

I also added the errorLabelContainer (though I do not require it) to check if it was receiving anything. Here as well, on error the errorLabelContainer selector receives the error message but on success it remains blank.

I need the valid class to be set since I use it for changing input background in CSS for visual indication to the user.

Here's the validation code that I have:

```
$('.registration-form').validate({
    debug           : true,
    onkeyup         : false,
    errorLabelContainer: '.message-box',
    onfocusout      : function(element) { var isvalid = $(element).valid(); console.log(isvalid); },
    rules           : { username                    : { required: true, alphanumeric: true, minlength: 3, remote: { url     : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
                                                                                                                    type    :'POST',
                                                                                                                    async   : false,
                                                                                                                    cache   : false,
                                                                                                                    timeout : 5000,
                                                                                                                    data    : { action: 'check_username',
                                                                                                                                username: function() { return $('input[name="username"]').val(); },
                                                                                                                                _ajax_nonce: ajaxVars._ajax_nonce
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                        }
                                                    },
                        email                       : { required: true, email: true, remote: {  url     : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
                                                                                                type    :'POST',
                                                                                                async   : false,
                                                                                                cache   : false,
                                                                                                timeout : 5000,
                                                                                                data    : { action: 'check_email',
                                                                                                            email: function() { return $('input[name="email"]').val(); },
                                                                                                            _ajax_nonce: ajaxVars._ajax_nonce
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                }
                                                    },
                        password                    : { required: true, minlength: 5 },
    }, // end rules
    messages        : { username                    : { required        : 'Please enter a username.',
                                                        alphanumeric    : 'Your username must be atleast 3 characters long and must only include alphabets, numbers or an underscore.',
                                                        minlength       : 'Your username must be atleast 3 characters long and must only include alphabets, numbers or an underscore.',
                                                        remote          : 'This username is already taken!'
                        },
                        email                       : { required        : 'Please enter an email address.',
                                                        email           : 'Please enter a valid email address.',
                                                        remote          : 'This email is already registered!'
                        },
                        password                    : 'Please provide a password for your new account. The password must be atleast 5 characters long.',
    }, // end messages
    submitHandler   : function(form) {
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                            success                 : show_reg_response,
                            url                     : ajaxVars.ajaxurl,
                            type                    : 'POST',
                            timeout                 : 10000,
                            clearForm               : true,
                            resetForm               : true
                        });
    } // end submitHandler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as yours, my current solution is replacing the remote validation with separate ajax.call to execute my validation logic (a little bit inconvenient since I should implement the show/hide method when appropriate).

Comment: Nope, haven't found a solution yet. Still searching.

Answer (score 0):

just for giggles, add a complete call back on your remote

```
    complete: function(data){
      $("#field_id").valid();                         
    }
```

This fixed the issue for me, not sure if it will for you or not depending on the rest of your code.
I am using a similar set of code as you.

Hope that helps

T